# c++ sdl: can i have an sdl-opengl window inside a menu and buttons i created with glade?

Tags: c++, opengl, gtk, glade, sdl-opengl

I used glade to create some gtk buttons.

1. is it possible to add an sdl-opengl window to a glade application ? if so, how ?
2. how can I interact between the gtk events and the sdl events inside the gtk window ?

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are at least two extensions to GTK that might help you: [GtkGLExt](http://projects.gnome.org/gtkglext/) and [Gtksdl](http://gtksdl.sourceforge.net/).

Gtksdl appears to be abandoned, but may contian some useful code. GtkGLExt is great if you're not relying on much SDL functionality beyond core OpenGL and events handling.

Comment: AFAIK, GtkGLExt is now integrated into Gtk directly.